# To prove $\sup |x^n g(x)| $ tends to zero as x tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[image]

In this particular problem,I am unable to understand how to prove the claim of sup(x) part. How can we use the information that g(1)=0.I need something to start off...

Comment: Consider taking the sup on the intervals $[0,1-\epsilon]$ and $[1-\epsilon,1]$. On the latter interval, $g\approx0$.

Comment: Mr. David... I would be obliged if you can provide a little elaborate answer/hint in the answer section as it helps a beginner like me to understand better... Thank you

Comment: @David Mitra....can you please share your work....I am also not able to understand how the problem will go

Comment: Do you know anything about "uniform convergence"?

Comment: No not yet....I am a beginner

Comment: @David Mitra....I am aware....

Comment: Can you see the statement is true if you take the sup over $[0, a]$, where $a\in (0,1)$?

Comment: @David Mitra Yes.... That I can

Comment: It's because $g$ is bounded and  $x^n\rightarrow0$ there, right? The problem at $x=1$ is that $x^n$ is constantly 1. But, on  $[a,1]$, you can use the fact that $g$ is continuous and $g(1)=0$. You can select $a$ so close to $1$ that $|g(x)|$ is as small as you like on $[a,1]$. So, you can make the $\sup$ of $|x^ng(x)|$ over $[a,1]$ as small as you like.

Comment: So, for the proof: let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $a$ so that $|x^ng(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,1]$. Now choose $N$ so that: for all $n>N$, $|x^n g(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in[0,a]$. This shows the $\sup$ is at most $\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, the $\sup$ must be $0$.